# Python Value Error: could not convert string to float dataframe (How can i find the position of the values)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn

I use the following python code to make classification. My problem is that the values that i get as  missing does not exist in my dataset. I want to create a function that prints the location and the value that can not be converted from string to float.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing as pre
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn import tree
import graphviz 


rec2007 = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/dimitris/Desktop/1.csv")
rec2007=rec2007.fillna(0)


columns = ["ACC_ID","ACCIDENT_TYPE","POLICE_DISTRICT","POLICE_STATION","DISTRICT_ACCIDENT_NO","ACCIDENT_TIME","NO_VEHICLES","NO_INJURED","NAMES_EXCHANGED_IND","POLICE_IND","ABANDON_IND","PHOTOS_IND","STRIKE_LEAVE_IND","POLICE_STATION_ACCIDENT_NO",  "FACTOR_A","PEDESTRIAN_ACTION","MAIN_ROAD","RESIDENCE_AREA",   "FACTOR_B","KM","MTR","FACTOR_C","TRAFFIC_CONTROL","ROAD_WIDTH","POINT_A","POINT_B","DIRECTION","BREAK_LANE_WIDTH","DIAGRAM_CODE",     "FACTOR_D","CONJUCTION_TYPE","ROUTE_PERMITTED","BARRIER","CONSTRICTION",   "PAVEMENT_TYPE","BREAK_LANE","SPEED_LIMIT","ROAD_WORK","BUS_STOP","PEDESTRIAN_CROSSING","LIGHTING","FIRST_EVENT_PLACE","ROAD_DESCR","PAVEMENT_STATUS","WEATHER","FIRST_EVENT","POLICE_OFFICER_GRADE","POLICE_OFFICER_NO","POLICE_CALLED","POLICE_ARRIVED","POLICE_TIME","AMBULANCE_CALLED_BY","AMBULANCE_CALLED","AMBULANCE_ARRIVED","AMBULANCE_TIME"]

all_X = rec2007[columns]
all_y = rec2007["AREA_CODE"]

train_X, test_X, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(
    all_X, all_y, test_size=0.2,random_state=0)

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier() 

clf.fit(train_X, train_y)

predictions = clf.predict(test_X)
```

## thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Thanks for comment!!

Comment: kindly post the entire error along with the question, as far as i can recall it tells what value it wasn't able to convert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to use `pd.to_numeric` passing in the `errors='coerce'` argument.

Then use `isna` and `idxmax` to return the first erroneous row.

For example, something like:

```
rec2007.loc[pd.to_numeric(rec2007.ACC_ID, errors='coerce').isna().idxmax(), ['ACC_ID']]
```

---

#### Edit

To check each column and only print out the invalid values, you could try:

```
for column in rec2007:
    if pd.to_numeric(rec2007[column], errors='coerce').isna().any():
        print(rec2007.loc[pd.to_numeric(rec2007[column], errors='coerce').isna().idxmax(), [column]])
```

Comment: This code line gave me a print of the column values of the first line of the csv. That means that this line has a problem? and how do i know in which column is the problematic value. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Hey @DIMITRIOS, I've updated my answer. Hopefully this helps.